# I am trying to obtain values for a percentage of beached particles but it is not reading correctly my files

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, particles

I am trying to obtain a variable for beached particles using data from nc files. I am using also foreach function to process the files in parallel and also create a loop.

However, when I run the loop; the following Error appears:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "number of points does not match the number of fields"
```

If I run one by one the commands; the same error appears after the command:

```
rcount <- rasterize(cbind(lon, lat), r, fun="count")  # count number of beached particles per cell
Error in .pointsToRaster(x, y, field = field, fun = fun, background = background,  : 
  number of points does not match the number of fields
```

I thought the error was that the number of coordinates and values were not the same. When I open the nc files, the data is as follows:
My files are like this:

```
23 variables (excluding dimension variables):
    double lonp[nt,ntrac]   (Chunking: [61,6500])  (Compression: shuffle,level 4)
        long_name: longitudinal position of drifter
        units: degrees
        time: tp
    double latp[nt,ntrac]   (Chunking: [61,6500])  (Compression: shuffle,level 4)
        long_name: latitudinal position of drifter
        units: degrees
        time: tp
    double tp[nt,ntrac]   (Chunking: [61,6500])  (Compression: shuffle,level 4)
        long_name: time at drifter locations
        units: seconds since 1968-05-23 00:00:00 GMT
    int nsteps[]   (Contiguous storage)  
        long_name: sets max time steps between time interpolations                               between model outputs
    int N[]   (Contiguous storage)  
        long_name: sets number of samplings of drifter track
    int ff[]   (Contiguous storage)  
        long_name: forward (1) or backward (-1) in time
    double tseas[]   (Contiguous storage)  
        long_name: time between model outputs
        units: second
    double ah[]   (Contiguous storage)  
        long_name: horizontal diffusion
        units: meter2 second-1
    double av[]   (Contiguous storage)  
        long_name: vertical diffusion
        units: meter2 second-1
    int do3d[]   (Contiguous storage)  
        long_name: flag for running in 3d (1) or 2d (0)
    int doturb[]   (Contiguous storage)  
        long_name: flag for using no subgrid parameterization (0),                         added     turbulent velocities (1), displacement to                         particle position on a circle (2), displacement to                         particle position on an ellipse (3)
    int doperiodic[]   (Contiguous storage)  
        long_name: flag for using periodic boundary conditions:                             none (0), in x-direction (1), in y-direction (2)
    int status[nt,ntrac]   (Contiguous storage)  
        long_name: flag for particle status: float (1), beach(2)
    int final_status[ntrac]   (Contiguous storage)  
        long_name: flag for particle status: float (1), beach(2)
    int beach_diag[ntrac]   (Contiguous storage)  
        long_name: flag for beaching diagnostics: trackpy (1), rscript(2)
    double age[ntrac]   (Contiguous storage)  
        units: days
        long_name: Age of the particle
    double msl[ntrac]   (Contiguous storage)  
        units: km
        long_name: Mean straight-line
    int input_id[ntrac]   (Contiguous storage)  
        long_name: input id code
    int new_status[nt,ntrac]   (Contiguous storage)  
        long_name: flag for particle status: float (1), beach(2)
    int ncstatus[nt,ntrac]   (Contiguous storage)  
        long_name: flag for particle status: float (1), beach(2)
    int ncfinal_status[ntrac]   (Contiguous storage)  
        long_name: flag for final particle status: float (1), beach(2)
    double ncmsl[ntrac]   (Contiguous storage)  
        units: km
        long_name: Mean straight-line
    int ncinput_id[ntrac]   (Contiguous storage)  
        long_name: input id code

 2 dimensions:
    ntrac  Size:13000 (no dimvar)
    nt  Size:121 (no dimvar)

4 global attributes:
    title: Postprocessed particles
    institution: http://www.socib.es/
    project: MEDCLIC
    history: D. March, 2023-05-06
```

My script  runs perfectly until the following part is reached:

```
  ## Locations
  idx <- which(mst == 2)  # identify beached events
  lon <- mlon[idx]  # retrieve longitude at beached events
  lat <- mlat[idx]  # retrieve latitude at beached events
```

At this point, this variables get empty, so when I try to rasterize, the error occurs.

Any suggestions? I am completely lost.

Comment: It is extremely difficult to provide any help without any data to reproduce the problem.